# Duplicate quotes in a postgres string

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function

I have a function that generates a new user in the database.
I would like to check if the email address contains any quotes and if it does, I would like to duplicate them.

For example, I have the following email address: test.o'test@test.com and I would like to transform it into test.o''test@test.com.

Could anybody help me with this?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you expect only one single quote (and not double or more), you could try using a simple replace:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET email = REPLACE(email, '''', '''''');
```

Comment: Maybe for better reading and understanding you can use double quotes like : `REPLACE(email, "'", "''")`

Comment: @ErgestBasha OK, but I won't _quote_ you on that `:-)` ... Double quotes may not be supported by all SQL engines, so I tried to give an answer that is as ANSI-friendly as possible.

Comment: @ErgestBasha, doesn't Postgresql read `"'"` as a column name?

Comment: Anyway, I'd add `WHERE email LIKE '%''%'`, to keep transaction size down.

Comment: @jarlh you are right I didn't notice PostgreSQL tag